# How properly declare a variable in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3, var, variable-declaration, let

I found quite interesting these different ways to declare a variable in Swift:

```
// METHOD 1
var dogName: String = "Charlie"

// METHOD 2
var dogName: String {
    return "Charlie"
}

// METHOD 3
let dogName = {
    return "Charlie"
}

// METHOD 4
var dogName: String = {
    return "Charlie"
}()
```

Obviously the method 3 declare a let and we known the difference; but why Swift allows the method 4?

**What's the difference between these four methods?**

I'm quite confusing in particular between method 2 and 4. In addition why the method 3 lose the final brackets compared to method 4?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Method 1 is a standard variable declaration for a String. It has a setter and a getter

```
var dogName: String = "Charlie"

print(dogName) -> "Charlie"
dogName = "Rex" // Valid
```

Method 2 is a computed property of type String and is read-only

```
var dogName: String {
    return "Charlie"
}

print(dogName) -> "Charlie"
dogName = "Rex" // Invalid as property is read-only
```

Method 3 is a read-only property of type () -> String, so basically a lambda function.

```
let dogName = {
    return "Charlie"
}

print(dogName) -> "(Function)"
print(dogName()) -> "Charlie"
dogName = "Rex" // Invalid as property is read-only
```

Method 4 is a closure that will be executed when the containing object is initialised. As it is a `var` you can replace it with another value

```
var dogName: String = {
    return "Charlie"
}()

print(dogName) -> "Charlie"
dogName = "Rex" // Valid
```

That being said, as Method 4 is a closure, you can execute other commands in it. Here is an example where you could use this construct to initialise a UILabel:

```
var dogNameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10))
    label.text = "Charlie"
    return label
}()
```

Comment: Well you are not that exactly right about the method 4. The closure will be executed at the initialization of the object, where the property is declared and not just when it is accessed. Thus, it is like a default property value assigned from result of that closure. But you are right, you can later replace it with anything else.

Comment: @OlegDanu You are completely right, I updated the answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Computed properties are not always read-only, BTW. You can define a `get` and `set` on computed properties to make them read-write. When declared as shown above, however, they implicitly only have a getter, which effectively makes them read-only. See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID259

Comment: @ItaiFerber Yes you are right a computed property is not always read-only, thanks for pointing that out. I removed the erroneous part of Method2's description.

Comment: @Sulthan That's not true. Method 3 is a lambda that you need to call in order to get the value. You can confirm this with `let x = { return 5 }; print(type(of: x))`

Answer (score 3):

To understand the differences let's use a more descriptive example

This is a class `Foo`

```
class Foo {

    var className = "Foo"

    var dogName1 : String { return "Charlie " + className }

    let dogName2 = {
        return "My name is Charlie"
    }

    var dogName3 : String = {
        var string = "My"
        string += " name"
        string += " is"
        string += " Charlie"
        print(string)
        return string
    }()

}
```

Now let's create an instance

```
let foo = Foo()
```

- **Method 1** is the stored property `className` with setter and getter

  ```
  let name = foo.className
  foo.className = "Bar"
  print(foo.className) // "Bar"
  ```
- **Method 2** is the computed property `dogName1` only with a getter. It can be used to compute values dynamically.

  ```
  print(foo.dogName1) // "Charlie Bar"
  ```
- **Method 3** is the closure `dogName2` of type `() -> String`. It can be assigned to a variable and later be executed

  ```
  let dogName = foo.dogName2 // assigns the closure but does not return the string.
  print(dogName()) // "My name is Charlie"
  ```
- **Method 4** is the variable `dogName3` which executes its closure immediately **once** when an instance `Foo()` is initialized (to be proved by the `print` line)

  ```
  print(foo.dogName3) // "My name is Charlie" but does not execute the closure and print `string` again
  ```
- There is even a **Method 5**: If you declare `dogName3` as `lazy`

  ```
  lazy var dogName3 : String = {
  ```

  the closure is not executed until the variable is accessed the first time. The advantage is you can even use `self` in the closure which is not possible in **Method 4**.

Answer (score 2):

I set up a quick test, renaming everything as `dogName1`,`dogName2`,`dogName3`, and `dogName4`. Then I added code to try to change each name to "Snoopy".

#2 and #3 didn't build, as the compiler knew they are both read only. (#2, despite being declared as a `var`, is set to always return "Charlie".

After commenting those two lines out, I set two breakpoints - on after initializing, one after trying to update.

Finally I tried doing a `print` of each one.

**Breakpoint #1:** #1 and #4 are set to "Charlie", #2 isn't there (because it isn't initialized) and #3 appears as initialized but with no value (because it wasn't called yet. And yes, the `()` at the end initializes something in memory.

**Breakpoint #2:** #1 and #4 were updated to "Snoopy".

**Results of `print`:** #1 and #4 were "Snoopy", #2 was "Charlie" and #3 was "(Function)".

**Conclusion:** There's no difference between #1 and #4. Each are declared `var` and have a default of "Charlie". #2, is read-only due to the `let` and will always return "Charlie". #3? It creates an instance and doesn't build if you try to change it - but I don't know how to use it.

I will update this answer if anyone has more to add about #3.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 is quite obvious.

In method 2 what you did is you defined a getter for given variable.

Type of dogName in method 3 is a `() -> String` and not `String`. What you initialized there is a named lambda.

In method 4 you initialize the variable with an anonymous(unnamed) lambda function that returns string.

Difference between 3 and 4 is that in 4th you call that function with () so you get String and in previous you don't so it's a function.